# Limiting Moves In Corona SDK

Tags: lua, match, coronasdk, limit

I am creating a Match-3 game in Corona SDK, and I would like to limit the amount of moves(or turns) a player can make before a gameover in called. I'd also like to display it to the player. Can anyone help me accomplish this, as this is my first big project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last year I finished a match-three game and there is an example for you to help:

```
local moves_count = 10 -- limite 10 moves

--Called move_success when player moved two cells succeed
function move_success()
    --Your code here
    --XXX
    --
    moves_count = moves_count - 1
    update_moves_display()
    check()
end

function check()
    --Your code here
    --XXX
    --

    while true do
        if XXXX then --level clear
            level_clear()
            return
        end

        if check_out_of_moves() then
            level_failed("outofmoves")
            return
        end

        --Check others you want
        --Your code here

        --
        return
    end
end

function update_moves_display()
    --Your code here
    --XXX
    --
end

function check_out_of_moves()
    return moves_count == 0
end

function level_failed(info)
    --Your code here
    --XXX
    --
end

function level_clear()
    --Your code here
    --XXX
    --
end
```

PS:My English is not very good, pardon me. ^_^

Comment: I'm having a hard time adding this into my code which is just a heavily modified version of Corona Crush (https://github.com/coronalabs/CoronaCrush/blob/master/main.lua). Is there any way you can elaborate on how to marry the two?

Comment: @W001W look here:[https://github.com/SES-xuelan/m3-for-W001W/blob/master/CoronaCrush-master-edit/main.lua](https://github.com/SES-xuelan/m3-for-W001W/blob/master/CoronaCrush-master-edit/main.lua) & compare them.

Comment: Thank You so much Albert! For the most part, everything works well.